# Map a Dictionary with array of values

Tags: swift

I want to convert a dictionary to an Array, by showing each `[String: [String]]` element as a string in the array (but the value may be empty).

So `["A": ["1","2"], "b": [], "c": ["5", "6"]]` will give `["b", "A1", "A2", "c5", "c6"]`.

I want to use map to do this, as the code I have feels unwieldy:

```swift
let messages: [String: [String]] = ["A": ["1","2"], "b": [], "c": ["5", "6"]]

var result: [String] = []

for message in messages {
    if !message.value.isEmpty {
        for value in message.value {
            result.append(message.key + value)
        }
    } else {
        result.append(message.key)
    }
}
```

How can I create the solution using map?

Comment: Why is "b" first, then "A", then "c"? Any reason?

Comment: Dictionaries do not have a predictable order. We can sort later, and on your machine the solution above may come up with an ordered answer by chance, but it won't be guaranteed. This isn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit shortened version using map

```
let messages: [String: [String]] = ["A": ["1","2"], "b": [], "c": ["5", "6"]]

let result = messages.map { dict in
    return dict.value.isEmpty ? ["\(dict.key)"] : dict.value.map { "\(dict.key)\($0)" }
}.flatMap{$0}
```

Comment: If you replace `map` with `flatMap` you won't need the `flatMap`, so you'll save a whole iteration on the result array. See my answer if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: Final note, you can also do `return dict.value.isEmpty ? [dict.key] : dict.value.map { dict.key + $0 }`, avoiding the String interpolation, it was a little strange for `dict.key` to use `"\(dict.key)"`, but maybe a more clearer for the sub mapping. So maybe it was a consistency choice? But at this point, that's totally nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use `reduce(into:_:)`, (I prefer this one):

```
let messages: [String: [String]] = ["A": ["1","2"], "b": [], "c": ["5", "6"]]

let output = messages.reduce(into: [String]()) { result, current in
    guard !current.value.isEmpty else { result.append(current.key); return }
    let sub = current.value.map { current.key + $0 }
    result.append(contentsOf: sub)
}

print("Output: \(output)")
```

Output:
$> Output: ["c5", "c6", "A1", "A2", "b"]

With a `map` and a `flatMap`, I found it less intuitive:

```
let output2 = messages.map { element -> [String] in
    guard !element.value.isEmpty else { return [element.key] }
    let sub = element.value.map { element.key + $0 }
    return sub
}.flatMap { $0 }

print("Output2: \(output2)")
```

Which then can be simplified with a direct call to `flatMap`, but that (`map` + `flatMap`) was to show the process, since this one will save you an iteration (you do only one instead of two):

```
let output3 = messages.flatMap { element -> [String] in
    guard !element.value.isEmpty else { return [element.key] }
    let sub = element.value.map { element.key + $0 }
    return sub
}
print("Output3: \(output3)")
```

I made the closure explicit enough, but that's up to you if you want to shorten them with ternary if etc.